# Error when trying to make the Linux kernel documentation

Tags: macos, makefile, linux-kernel, gnu-make

I have Linux git repository cloned, latest version of sphinx, GNU make, python, and all dependencies handled, running on MacOS, I am getting the following error when I attempt to make the linux documentation:

```
% make xmldocs
make[1]: *** Documentation/Kbuild: Is a directory.  Stop.
make: *** [Makefile:1816: xmldocs] Error 2
```

I run `make` at top-level of linux directory that I cloned.

I've also found that I could potentially do this by `scripts/kernel-doc` but I am unsure how to specify all the relevant files as its argument.

Comment: I couldn't get the dependencies installed properly on the Linux VM I was using, and I have them on my Macbook.

Comment: When I ran `make xmldocs`, got the same error as yours, whereas it ran to completion in my Ubuntu VM.

Comment: I have a bit of a dependency problem on my ArchLinux VM to do with my python packages, and I can't figure out pacman for the life of me. If it's not too much to ask, could you provide either the image you are using or the documentations you built?

Comment: My end-goal has been to install `man 9` using the built `xmldocs`.

Comment: I downloaded `linux-6.3-rc7.tar.gz`, untared it and ran `make xmldocs`. I'm using `Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS (Focal Fossa)`. If you repost your question regarding your problems on Linux, you've got better chance to get an answer.

Comment: It's just problems on problems @Philippe . Would you be able to make available your `xmldocs` if it's not too much to ask, or otherwise point me toward where I could find such a thing?

Comment: What I meant is that it's much much harder to achieve your goal on MacOS than on Linux.

Comment: What do you mean by `make available your xmldocs` ?

Comment: I mean if you could share your made documentation, or provide me a place to find the made documentation in any of the formats. For me, the only reason I need them is for developing some kernel stuff for my OS class.

Comment: `Is a directory` is a message from `unlink`. Does the error go away if you add `.PRECIOUS: %/.` to avoid deleting the directory? See [Chained Rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html#Chained-Rules "GNU Make manual"), cf. [How do I get GNU make to remove intermediate directories created by implicit rules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15151118/how-do-i-get-gnu-make-to-remove-intermediate-directories-created-by-implicit-rul/15157891#15157891) (prints `rm -f` but calls `unlink(2)`).

Comment: No @urznow . I tried adding that in both Makefiles

Answer (score 1):

This error is likely caused by the fact you have unpacked Linux kernel source tree into a case-insensitive filesystem.

MacOS doesn't use a case sensitive file system by default (in order to avoid compatibility issues with some applications).

Make sure to use as source tree path for linux kernel a **case-sensitive** file system, if not, create a partition with case sensitive filesystem:

1. Open Disk Utility.
2. Select disk you want to partition.
3. Click partition button.
4. Configure the partition selecting as format **Mac OS Extended (Case-sensitive, Journaled)** or **APFS (Case-sensitive)**.

[image]

If you don't want to partition the disk "directly", as alternative, you could use a Virtual Machine with a case sensitive virtual disk (obviously).